# Increase margin of label in stat_cor

Tags: r, ggplot2

The white space of the label does not scale well with increased text size

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)


# plot the data using ggplot
p <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() 

p <- p + stat_cor(aes(label = ..rr.label..), 
                  color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 3)
```

[image]

changing size to 10:

```
p <- p + stat_cor(aes(label = ..rr.label..), 
                  color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 10)
```

[image]

I want the R2 centered in the white box not spilling out. I was hoping `label.size` would do it, but just increases the border on the label

Answer (score 1):

Specify `hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5` will centre your text within the label's boundaries. Thereafter, you can adjust the label's position for your actual use case (which I assume is not the iris dataset) so that it's within the plot's boundaries and doesn't cover too many data points.

For example:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_point() + 
  stat_cor(aes(label = after_stat(rr.label)), 
           color = "red", geom = "label", digits = 2, size = 10, 
           hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, 
           label.x.npc = 0.75, label.y.npc = 0.9)
# label.x.npc & label.y.npc take values between [0, 1]
```

[image: plot]